# Error 1064 when trying to create a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

Here is the code:

```
create table `team`.`User`( 
   `UserID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `Username` text(30) NOT NULL , 
   `Email` text(30) NOT NULL , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`)
 )  Engine= [default] comment='' row_format=Default
```

And the error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'[default] comment='' row_format=Default' at line 6
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** This code was automatically generated by SQLyog. It seems that the Engine bit is causing the problem. Does anyone know how to use SQLyog to set the default engine?

Comment: If you want to use the default engine then just leave that part from your create table statement.

Comment: What did you not understand in `"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use"`?

Comment: Please, don't change your question. You have many answers here that solve problem you posted. If you need, post another question, mentioning this question in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, square brackets don't have any special meaning in MySQL. You're probably confused with some other DBMS.

[Valid syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) for the ENGINE keyword is `ENGINE [=] engine_name`. E.g.:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

... or

```
ENGINE InnoDB
```

If you don't care about the storage engine, remove the clause and MySQL will use the default.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use default engine you should try to remove `Engine= [default]` part.
Your query should be

```
CREATE TABLE `team`.`User`( 
   `UserID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `Username` TEXT(30) NOT NULL , 
   `Email` TEXT(30) NOT NULL , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`)
 )  comment=''
```

Answer (score 1):

`Engine= [default]`, try with `Engine= MyISAM`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Your create query is fault. 
Take a look at the manual [and what is the correct syntax for ENGINE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html)